# Php exec is not running properly when called from Java on localhost

Tags: java, php, exec, httpurlconnection

I have a problem running the exec command from within a php script.
here's the detailed scenario:

- I have an executable **my_exe** which runs from command line. This executable uses an environment variable, so I prepend the command with `MY_VARIABLE='value'` (works fine).
- I use the **exec** command to run this executable from a Php script. ex: `exec("MY_VARIABLE='value' my_exe");` (works fine too, tested in a browser)
- The problem is in this part. When I call the php script from a Java program using **HttpUrlConnection**, I have two cases: if I run the Java program from outside the server (using public IP address) I get the good results, but when I run it from the server (using local IP, form command line ex. "`java -jar /path/to/my/jar`"), the Php works but the exec doesn't seem to be working properly. The environment variable is not being set in this case, so the executable runs but without the right values, so I get no results.

Any help is appreciated. I'm really stuck here. My guess is that there is a  problem with Php or Java permissions, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: note: I'm using a ubuntu server

Answer (score 0):

Strange command `exec("MY_VARIABLE='value' my_exe");`... it will work only on linux machine and will not on windows.
As a first step, try to rewrite you `php` code like this:

```
putenv("MY_VARIABLE=value");
exec("my_exe");
```

and see what happen.

Comment: btw, did you run same Java program for both cases?

Comment: And if so, could you show how did you call **HttpUrlConnection** in Java?

Comment: yes, I run the same java from both cases. that's what dazzled me. I use the HTtpUrlConnection the classic way

Comment: I mean, what *url* did you use for the **HttpUrlConnection** in both cases?

Comment: How did you run your java from outside the server? And could you show some of your code (`php` and `java`)? I will try to catch that bug.